# Subscribing to ActiveMQ Artemis queue from .Net app using ActiveMQ.Artemis.Client

Tags: .net, amqp, activemq-artemis

I'm trying to pull messages from a durable queue (multicast under an address) in ActiveMQ Artemis from a .Net application using ActiveMQ.Artemis.Client. ActiveMQ Artemis is on a remote server, but I'm running the .Net app locally to test this library.

My issue is, the below code works sometimes. Sometimes it pulls a message, but usually it gets stuck at this line perpetually:

```
await connectionFactory.CreateAsync()
```

There are messages in the queue. When I check the journalctrl logs for ActiveMQ Artemis, I see that the connection has timed out, with the following error:

```
ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) on acceptor "ssl-acceptor" during protocol handshake with /[local ip]:55454 has occurred.
```

The ActiveMQ Artemis end looks OK. I can subscribe to the address::queue elsewhere consistently, like using Python stomp library.

Here is the application code, just a simple test from a console app:

```
using ActiveMQ.Artemis.Client;


var connectionFactory = new ActiveMQ.Artemis.Client.ConnectionFactory();
var endpoint = Endpoint.Create(host: "this.systems", port: "port", user: "user", password: "password", scheme: Scheme.Amqps);

// Sticks here
var connection = await connectionFactory.CreateAsync(endpoint);

var consumer = await connection.CreateConsumerAsync(new ConsumerConfiguration() { Address = "test2.address", Queue = "test2.queue" });

var message = await consumer.ReceiveAsync();
var body = message.GetBody<string>();
System.Console.WriteLine(body);

await connection.DisposeAsync();
```

Comment: You could enable SSL debugging in Java adding the following argument ` -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake`, see https://access.redhat.com/solutions/973783. What error you get before AMQ224088 enabling SSL debugging?

Comment: All the evidence indicates that this is either a client issue or an environmental issue (e.g. network) outside the broker's control. Is there any way to get something like a thread dump in .NET so that you could see exactly what the client is doing when it's stuck?